# How to get resource name for an image which is linked in my project?

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know what i am missing here. I've linked an image file in my wpf application and i want to retrieve this image in a WinFormHost. So i am trying to take **ResourceSet** from my **ResourceManager**. But when i try to traverse the **DictionaryEntry** in **ResourceSet**, it does not return any dictionary entry?

```
ResourceManager resMan = Application.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
ResourceSet rSet = resMan.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
```

Here's how i am trying to get dictionary entry. It does not print any dictionary entry.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rSet)
{
    string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
    Logger.Print(resouceKey);
}
```

Comment: If you added the image to your Resources.resx file in the application, you should be able to access it like an object. E.g. add `using project_name.Properties;`  
This should give you access to the image `Resources.MyImageName`

Comment: "I've linked an image file in my wpf application" What exactly does that mean? Please clarify how exactly the image file is supposed to be contained in or referenced by your application.

Comment: @Clemens : I've linked all the images in a folder and I am using msbuild to compile my binary. The uri of the file is **pack://application:,,,/Assets/file.png**. I want to get its manifest resource name.

Comment: [ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) *retrieves resources from a binary .resources file that is embedded in an assembly or from a standalone .resources file*. This is something different than adding files with Build Action `Resource` to a VS project. ResourceManager can't retrieve such resource files.

Comment: @Clemens How do you suggest to get the info of such resources? Or am i doing the incorrect way?